# « Du haut de » + substantif : existe-t-il un emploi analogique/au figuré non « péjoratif » (hautain) ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, locutions

On a une question sur la locution [*du haut de*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/37205/19187) et un substantif dans un contexte particulier. [Ac.9](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/haut) parle d'un sens concret (*le point élevé qu'on indique*) ou au figuré « en lui marquant du mépris ou de l'indifférence ». Le TLFi isole *du [haut](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/haut/1) du ciel* au figuré du sens « péjoratif »...

Dans son courriel aux internautes, l'[Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/abdul-s-senegal) répond : « Hormis au sens propre (*Il me toisait du haut de ses deux mètres*), on emploie *du haut de* pour indiquer qu'une chose se fait d’une façon hautaine, avec une certaine supériorité. » (Académie française)

Le sens « concret » par analogie n'impliquant pas la hauteur (comme par exemple visant des *réalisations*) ou le sens au figuré non péjoratif existe-t-il ; s'agit-il d'une extension de sens qui s'éloigne de la norme de manière significative (pourquoi, pourquoi pas) ; d'autres locutions (prépositives etc.) ou d'autres formulations sont-elles employées dans ce genre de contexte ?

Answer (score 1):

La question de savoir si l'extension de sens est "abusive", est difficile à juger en l'instant. Si on veut être très rigide, toute extension de sens est abusive si elle n'est pas déjà courante, et là on transforme un peu la question de l'évolution linguistique en serpent qui se mord la queue...

C'est parfaitement possible que la locution soit en train d'évoluer vers un sens plus neutre, sans ces connotations négative. Personnellement, ce serait la première fois que je la vois employée comme ça.

Comment: Je vais reformuler...